# Part of a Mesh Not Being Included in Bones

Tags: mesh, armature, bones, keyframes

beginner here. Seeking help on below.

I'm having issue on the top part of my mesh not being included in the armature/bone.

This is the view when I'm not doing any movement:

[image]

But when I try to rotate or already try adding keyframes, the top is not being included.

[image]

In the modelling part of this low poly, I tried:

1. Edit mode
2. Select the top
3. Duplicate the top (the shift + D only)
4. Scale to somehow make it look outstanding from the head.

Would really appreciate your help and explanation. I thought if I only use one mesh, bone would consider it as one.

Comment: Select this mesh in Edit mode and assign it to the vertex group that has the same name as the head bone?

Comment: @moonboots this works. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select this mesh in *Edit* mode and assign it to the vertex group that has the same name as the head bone:

[image]